# Having trouble in updating one field in my model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have my web api action `AddParticipant` that accepts Event Id

I add a row to my `ParticipantList` (the event Id and userId)

I wanted to increment a single field in my `Events` model that is `ParticipantList`. However, I'm getting an error

> "Attaching an entity of type `'xx.Models.Event'` failed because another entity of the same type already has the same `primary key` value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. "

What can be a workaround on this?

```
public IHttpActionResult AddParticipant(int id)
{
    var Participant = new ParticipantList
    {
        EventId = id,
        ParticipantId = base.ControllerContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity.GetUserId()

    };

    db.ParticipantList.Add(Participant);
    db.SaveChanges();

    var eventupdated = new Event()
    {
        Id = id,
        ParticipantCount = db.Events.Find(id).ParticipantCount++
    };

    using (db)
    {
        db.Events.Attach(eventupdated);
        db.Entry(eventupdated).Property(x => x.ParticipantCount).IsModified = true;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: You code for getting `eventupdated` is a bit strange. Why not just `var event = db.Events.Find(id); event.ParticipantCount++`; and then save it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
 var eventupdated = new Event()
    {
        Id = id,
        ParticipantCount = db.Events.Find(id).ParticipantCount++
    };

    using (db)
    {
        db.Events.Attach(eventupdated);
        db.Entry(eventupdated).Property(x => x.ParticipantCount).IsModified = true;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

by

```
var eventupdated = db.Events.Find(id);
eventupdated.ParticipantCount= eventupdated.ParticipantCount++;//OR just eventupdated.ParticipantCount++;
db.SaveChanges();
```